# Grey on black 'suggestion' text?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, moto-x, swiftkey, snapchat

**My Solution:** turn off autocomplete and autocorrect completely, and use a different keyboard.

What option will help me turn off this 
strange text that doesn't want to go away in the text boxes of some apps like Snapchat? I'm hoping someone will recognize what this is.

[image: Screenshot of problem]

<sup>Click image for larger version</sup>

Moto X using Swiftkey.

The text appears when the keyboard is focused, and nothing seems to interact with it or remove it. It only appears in Snapchat currently.